# Parsing JSON Array Data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to get data out of some JSON DATA. I'm using the following lines to decode it right now

`$json_array = (array)(json_decode($response));`

When I print my JSON Decoded array, I have the following data below:
I would like to get the details from the details section, where there is multiple sets of from/to_date's, and up/down numbers. Nothing I seem to do works though to get me to that data. I can print out the data from other areas like usage, but, I can't get into the details.

```
Array ( 
    [resp_code] => SUCCESS 
    [caller_ref] => 2017092002282130006180 
    [server_ref] => 2017092002282169760291 
    [data] => stdClass Object ( 
        [type] => monthly
        [group_id] => 19 
        [device_id] => 32
        [sn] => sn1234
        [usages] => Array ( 
            [0] => stdClass Object (
                [from_date] => 2017-09-01T00:00:00 
                [to_date] => 2017-09-30T23:59:59 
                [up] => 22370
                [down] => 119217
                [ts] => 2017-09-01T00:00:00 
            )
        ) 
        [details] => stdClass Object (
            [3] => Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object (
                    [from_date] => 2017-09-01T00:00:00 
                    [to_date] => 2017-09-30T23:59:59 
                    [up] => 5522 
                    [down] => 40301 
                    [ts] => 2017-09-01T00:00:00 
                ) 
            ) 
            [2] => Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [from_date] => 2017-09-01T00:00:00 
                    [to_date] => 2017-09-30T23:59:59
                    [up] => 6905 
                    [down] => 32029 
                    [ts] => 2017-09-01T00:00:00
                ) 
            )
        )
     )
)
```

Comment: Can you provide me the actual JSON string?

Comment: @JustinF Take 5 mins to learn the editor, adding `<BR>` is not how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with objects?

```
$obj = json_decode($response);

echo $obj->data->details[0]->from_date;
```

Or to loop it:

```
foreach ($obj->data->details as $item) {
    echo $item->from_date;
    // same goes for: to_date, up etc.
}
```

Simple and sexy!

**Update:**
It looks as if `$item` would be an array as well, so if you have problems try:

```
foreach ($obj->data->details as $item) {
    echo $item[0]->from_date;
    // same goes for: to_date, up etc.
}
```